# How do I extract data from Json_response to be used in python

Tags: python, json, get, sms-gateway

I am trying to integrate two APIs

1. from metering platform that should send notifications via sms.
2. API is an sms platform to deliver the messages.

Python Code;

```
import africastalking
import requests
import json

# Initialize SDK
username = "sandbox" # use 'sandbox' for development in the test environment
# use your sandbox app API key for development in the test environment
api_key = "auth_key"
africastalking.initialize(username, api_key)


# Initialize a service e.g. SMS
sms = africastalking.SMS

url = "https://nay-bokani.sparkmeter.cloud/api/v0/sms/outgoing"

payload = json.dumps({
  "mark_delivered": False
})
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authentication-Token': 'auth_key'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

# print()
json_response = response.json()

if json_response['status'] == 'success':
  if json_response["messages"][0]["timestamp"] == max("timestamp"):
    for s in range(len(json_response['messages'])):
      response = sms.send(json_response['messages']['text'], [json_response['messages']['phone_number']])
    print(response)

print(response.text)
```

json response

```
{
  "error": null,
  "messages": [ 
    {
      "id": "46186176-ba91-4072-a93e-0fc089dea750",
      "phone_number": "+2348000000000",
      "text": "You've just been credited with N10.00 worth of energy",
      "timestamp": "2021-06-09T10:14:10.795818"
    },
    {
      "id": "6709099c-22c8-4df5-88e1-24284d8ff61f",
      "phone_number": "+2348111111111",
      "text": "You've just been credited with N500.00 worth of energy",
      "timestamp": "2021-06-09T10:32:11.885605"
    }
  ],
  "status": "success"
}
```

I need to be able to extract the phone number and text and use it to send an auto sms using the sms API. I tried to use parse using the recent timestamp, but that will be a problem when multiple json data is returned.

Comment: The same way you extract data from any `dict` or `list`: use indexing. The fact that your `json_response` came from a JSON object is irrelevant.

Comment: Are you using timestamp to check if it's a new response?

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

#cannot use the real sms.send function so define a dummy one
def dummy_sms_send(txt, phone):
    print(txt, phone)

json_response = """
{
  "error": null,
  "messages": [ 
    {
      "id": "46186176-ba91-4072-a93e-0fc089dea750",
      "phone_number": "+2348000000000",
      "text": "You've just been credited with N10.00 worth of energy",
      "timestamp": "2021-06-09T10:14:10.795818"
    },
    {
      "id": "6709099c-22c8-4df5-88e1-24284d8ff61f",
      "phone_number": "+2348111111111",
      "text": "You've just been credited with N500.00 worth of energy",
      "timestamp": "2021-06-09T10:32:11.885605"
    }
  ],
  "status": "success"
}
"""

decoded_response = json.loads(json_response)
if decoded_response["status"] == "success":
    for msg in decoded_response["messages"]:
        dummy_sms_send(msg["text"], msg["phone_number"])
```